# MySQL need help setting up trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers

I am trying to set up a `TRIGGER` to clear empty strings before `INSERT`.  Not rocket science but I can't find the error in my syntax!

Here is the `TRIGGER` itself

```
USE `ga_abtest_logging`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_empty
    BEFORE INSERT ON daily_analytics
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF profileID = '' 
                THEN SET profileID = NULL
            END IF;
        END$$
```

Here is what workbench is showing:

[image: DELIMITER]

On hover over the `END IF` it reads `syntax error, unexpected END, expecting ';'`

Could I have a problem with the settings on my DB?  I have gone through the MySQL docs and I think the trigger looks right!  Does anyone see anything obviously wrong?

Comment: When defining a trigger or stored procedure change your `DELIMITER` to something other than `;`

Comment: IF NEW.profileId='' then set NEW.ProfileID=NULL. Give this a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a few changes:

- Use the `NEW.` prefix when referencing a column value
- Add a semi-colon at the end of the line where you set the value

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_b_ins_daily_analytics BEFORE INSERT ON daily_analytics FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.profileID = '')
  THEN
    SET NEW.profileID = NULL;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work.

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_empty  
    BEFORE INSERT ON daily_analytics  
        FOR EACH ROW  
        BEGIN  
            IF NEW.profileID = ''  
                THEN SET NEW.profileID = NULL;  
            END IF;  
        END;$$  
DELIMITER ;
```